# Why is a new AppDomain being created every few seconds (WCF/IIS 7)?

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to debug some mischievous MT code.  The most recent, most crazy thing (after adding extensive logging) seems to be that on my single-worker-process, single-machine IIS-hosted WCF service, several app domains are created at the start for the first few requests and then every few seconds another one is created.

Each line below is logged from roughly the following stack trace:

```
AddItem (WCF service method)
calls SomeRepositoryClass.Open (instance of class was created for this request)
calls WritePlanBufferManager constructor (static instance), accessed in lock construct (on static readonly object field)
```

Log (A=AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id, T=Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId):

```
    Line 1: [21:21:21.7544122 A:002 T:011] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 2
    Line 2: [21:21:31.0299427 A:004 T:008] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 4
    Line 3: [21:21:36.5912608 A:006 T:012] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 6
    Line 4: [21:21:37.9533387 A:008 T:010] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 8
    Line 670: [21:21:41.1065191 A:010 T:020] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 10
    Line 1336: [21:21:43.4236516 A:012 T:020] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 12
    Line 2002: [21:21:45.8347895 A:014 T:020] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 14
    Line 2656: [21:21:48.2479276 A:016 T:020] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 16
    Line 3322: [21:21:50.9600827 A:018 T:020] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 18
    Line 3988: [21:21:53.2752151 A:020 T:010] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 20
    Line 4654: [21:21:55.7353558 A:022 T:020] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 22
    Line 5320: [21:21:58.0414877 A:024 T:007] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 24
    Line 5984: [21:22:00.5546315 A:026 T:020] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 26
    Line 6650: [21:22:02.9327675 A:028 T:020] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 28
    Line 7316: [21:22:05.4109092 A:030 T:020] Created new WritePlanBufferManager for appdomain 30
    ....many more
```

There's *plenty* of other stuff I'm trying to work out, but I'd like to limit my problems to one AppDomain at a time, initially.

Each of these `WritePlanBufferManager` objects are used to create several (~13) threads for delayed/async queuing and processing of items.

The service config is bog-standard, minimal, out-of-the-box.  Web.config is pretty much empty, and has no WCF config.

App Pool has Maximum Worker Processes = 1, Rapid Fail Protection/startup/shutdown/Ping all disabled.  The service is being hammered with requests from a single client, single thread.

So, the basic question - why am I getting multiple AppDomains, why are additional AppDomains created frequently?

---

*Update*: It seems as if my AppDomains are being unloaded and all threads aborted after a few seconds (approx. one minute).  However, on the App Pool there's no CPU limit, an idle timeout of several days, 1 maximum worker process, Ping is disabled (and timeouts set to several days), Rapid-Fail protection is disabled and all Process Recycling options are turned off.

So, the question becomes, why are my AppDomain(s) being unloaded - nothing in the event log - and as such my threads being aborted?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your service [InstanceContext](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/23/understanding-instancecontext-in-wcf/) is configured for either per call or per session. WCF does implement an instance caching mechanism so you're seeing that process spin up.

If you want a true singleton instance implementation then you need to set InstanceContext to single (and ConcurrencyMode to multi-threaded based on your question info). Another way to get a singleton instance is to write code to use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx) of the ServiceHost.

I'm in the camp that discourages the use of a singleton WCF service instancee in production because I trust the WCF framework to do a much better job of handling requests through per-call instancing than I can by rolling my own. YMMV :)

Comment: I'll give that a go now.  In the meantime - I have part of my call that must be executed before the service returns, and 90% of the work which can be executed in the few seconds following and is better batched-up and persisted.  I figured a "staticly-kept" manager of threads would do the job well.  What's an appropriate alternative in your opinion?  Do I really need to add another roundtrip to a Windows Service etc?

Comment: No cigar, I'm afraid.  Same behavior exactly, I'm using `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]`.  Only 3 appdomains initially but still, more than one..

Comment: Just to be clear, sounds like your comment is referring to client-side code. If so then it'll depend on what hosts the client code. If it is a web app hosted in IIS then the client will be in a similar environment to your service but with the multi-threading constraints of ASP.NET. If not then yes, implementing a thread manager to handle  batching would be viable. I wouldn't try to implement a thread manager in an ASP.NET based client though (too complex, makes my brain hurt).

Comment: Actually, that sounds right for singleton. I have never look at the WCF source code but to do all that it does it most likely creates "sub" AppDomains for memory management. Remember, WCF was originally written when dynamically created assemblies could not unloaded from memory without closing the AppDomain they were created in. As long as the AppDomains don't keep being spun up, then you've got your singleton.

Comment: It's all server-side code here.  I'm still pretty lost, I'm not sure what you mean by client-side code

Comment: It seems like WCF is making too much multi-threading "noise" for you. I'd say to develop your code in a plain vanilla Windows Service or console host to get your threading algorithms working correctly and then integrate the resulting code into the WCF hosting scenario you're planning on using.

Comment: I'm confident it works fine outside of WCF, and I'm working backwards from the other direction now.  I've tried your suggestion but still there are multiple AppDomains and multiple instances of 'static' objects.  Do you have any other suggestions? :/

Comment: I've haven't dug that far into the implementation of WCF service instances. If you're familiar with WinDbg, there is a DumpDomain command in SOS that would a starting point to seeing what is actually in memory. Sorry can be more helpful...